# if/elif mash up

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my second question on this site and both of them deal with 'if' statements not working as expected.
I've been learning Python for about 3-4 months and I remember back at the beginning when i was learning 'for', 'if's and 'while's I remember thinking that the 'if' statement is the simplest of the three; I'm starting to come to the realization that 'if' statements aren't as clear cut as I once thought.

I'm writing a converter that converts between binary, decimal and hex without using any Python built-in math functions. I am using tkinter.

The problem I will ask about deals with when the convert from 'binary' radio button is selected.  below the 3 'convert from' radio buttons are 3 'convert to' check boxes.
The following code is meant to convert from binary to decimal if the dec_bttn checkbox is checked and to hex if the hex_bttn checkbox is selected:

```
def from_binary(self, dec_bttn, hex_bttn):
    """ Performs conversion from base2 to base10 and base16. """
    bits = '1010'               #actual code used -> self.input_str.get()
    exp =  len(bits) -1         #actual code used -> len(self.input_str.get()) - 1

    # operate on valid string
    # converts to decimal
    if self.dec_bttn:           
        dtot = 0
        while exp >= 1:
            for i in bits[:-1]:
                if i == "1":
                    dtot += 2**exp
                elif i == "0":
                    dtot = dtot                        
                exp -= 1

            if bits[-1] == "1":
                dtot += 1

            self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
            self.output_disp.insert(0.0, dtot)


    # convert to hex

    elif self.hex_bttn:
        hex_digits = {
                      10: 'a', 11: 'b',
                      12: 'c', 13: 'd',
                      14: 'e', 15: 'f'
                      }
        string_length = len(bits)
        exp = len(bits) - 1
        if string_length <= 4:
            htot = 0
            while exp >= 1:
                for i in bits[:-1]:
                    if i == "1":
                        htot += 2**exp
                    elif i == "0":
                        htot = htot                        
                    exp -= 1

                if bits[-1] == "1":
                    htot += 1

            for i in hex_digits.keys():
                if i == htot:
                    htot = hex_digits[i]
                else:
                    htot = htot

            self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
            self.output_disp.insert(0.0, htot)
```

I have posted the entire 'from_binary' method. This is probably slightly more than needed but alittle too much is better than neglecting any amount.

Because I have to eventually break the string up into half byte strings for the hex conversion it is set up now as <= 4. So I am only testing it using 4 bits strings.

As it stands right now, using 'elif self.hex_bttn' it converts binary to decimal regardless of which checkbox is selected.
If I change that to 'if self.hex_bttn' then it converts to hex regardless of which checkbox is selected.

The math and everything works right and outputs correctly. Its just the mix up with these 'if' statements that is holding up my progress.
To my beginners mind it seems like a fairly straightforward test, but I am obviously missing something.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could put me on the right path.

Blessings
F.

Comment: What does `print self.hex_bttn` output? `if` statements default to `True` if the expression is not explicitly false (`[]`, `{}`, `0`, `False`, `None`, `''`).

Comment: Leaving it as is: elif self.hex_bttn I tried that in 3 postition. 1) at the end of the method outside both if blocks and got PY_VAR2. 2) Immediately after the elif self.hex_bttn and got nothing in return. and 3) immediately after if self.dec_bttn and got PY_VAR2 again.

Comment: What is the value of `self.hex_bttn`?

Comment: I have them both set as BooleanVar(). Which means that I am in the belief that if one is selected that means True and not selected = False.

Comment: Try `if self.het_bttn.get()`.

Comment: @Blender: Heh, should I just delete my answer? Your comments answered him first, I was just too slow.

Comment: Yes, that worked thank you.  The crazy thing is that before I tried it I was going to comment first saying that that was the original way that I had it, and I was getting an exception. I decided to try it again before commenting and it worked fine which is really weird. I must have made another alteration along the way that reverted things to work with get() again. hard to explain, but thank yyou very much, because without you I never would have tried it again.

Comment: Hay Blender, voithos. Would one of you mind explaining why the if/elif was changing its behaviour depending on whether i used if or elif before I added the 'get()'? thanks, if you have the time

Comment: @Icsilk: The if/elif blocks are mutually exclusive; if one of the blocks is executed, then the other _won't_. So, since the first `if` was always True, the first block would always be executed. Of course, if you switched the literal order of the blocks, then whichever came first would be executed because the object was always evaluated as True. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @voithos, yeah it does. Thank you. Makes complete sense and kinda the same logic I have realized since getting this recent problem figured out. EDIT: actually I just got to thinking that it is still weird because using an elif caused the preceding if to always run but if I changed the elif to if (making two if's) then the second if was always run. That is what is a bit confusing, and doesnt quite jive with the logic I was coming to accept about the flow.

Comment: When you use `if` both times, _both_ blocks run because they're completely independent. You just can't tell that they both run because the hexadecimal result computed by the second block _overwrites_ the decimal result computed by the first block. But if you use `elif` for the second block, then  it's linked to the preceding `if`. The mere fact that the `if` condition was true prevents the `elif` block from running, so the decimal result sticks around.

Comment: By the way, the parameters `dec_bttn` and `hex_bttn` that you pass to this method never get used, so you might want to remove them for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

The `if` statement, and it's complement `elif`, work on [Boolean values](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans). If a variable, or whatever is being tested, is not Boolean already, then it is *coerced* and understood in a true/false fashion.

**Any object that is non-zero, and not empty, is interpreted as being "True".** So, assuming that `dec_bttn` and `hex_bttn` are Tkinter checkboxes, then Python is checking the Boolean value of the checkboxes *themselves* and, seeing that they are true, proceeds to execute the first `if` block every time.

Somewhere in your code you're probably initializing the Tkinter checkboxes like this:

```
self.dec_bttn = Checkbutton(root, Text='To decimal', ... )
self.hex_bttn = Checkbutton(root, Text='To hex', ... )
```

Instead of initializing them like this, you need to have variables that can store the "checked" state of the checkboxes, like so:

```
self.dec_checked = IntVar()
self.hex_checked = IntVar()

self.dec_bttn = Checkbutton(root, Text='To decimal',
                    variable=self.dec_checked, ... )
self.hex_bttn = Checkbutton(root, Text='To hex',
                    variable=self.hex_checked, ... )
```

Notice the `IntVar`. That is where the value is stored. But, you don't have to use `IntVar`, you can also use `BooleanVar`, or any other Tkinter variable type, in fact.

But, I digress, I see that you're already using a `BooleanVar`. So, most of this you already knew. But, the reason why just checking `self.dec_bttn` doesn't work is because `dec_bttn` is **an object**, not just a simple Boolean value.

**Use `self.dec_bttn.get()` in your `if` statement to check the states of the checkboxes.**

Check out the [Tkinter reference](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html) for some other methods that are associated with the Tkinter variable types.

Comment: Yes I had them set as self.dec_bttn = BooleanVar() etc. I just changed the all (self.bin_bttn, self.dec_bttn and self.hex_bttn) to IntVar() and am getting the same result.

Comment: @Icsilk: As Blender mentioned, you need to use the `.get()` method of the variable objects. And, you can use `BooleanVar` if you'd like.

Comment: It is working now, thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you `self.dec_bttn` and `self.hex_bttn` evaluate to true, probably because, as @voithos says, you should `.get()` the values from the objects.

Here is a perfectly serviceable binary-string-to-number converter:

```
def binary_to_number(binary_string):
    total = 0
    for c in binary_string:
        total = total * 2 + (c == "1")
    return total
```

Then your code could be like this:

```
def binary_to_number(binary_string):
    total = 0
    for c in binary_string:
        total = total * 2 + (c == "1")
    return total

def binary_to_decimal(binary_string):
    return str(binary_to_number(binary_string))

def binary_to_hex(binary_string):
    hex_digits = {
        10: 'a', 11: 'b',
        12: 'c', 13: 'd',
        14: 'e', 15: 'f'
    }
    tot = binary_to_number(bits)
    return str(hex_digits.get(tot, tot))

if self.dec_bttn.get():           
    self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
    self.output_disp.insert(0.0, binary_to_decimal(bits))

elif self.hex_bttn.get():
    self.output_disp.delete(0.0, END)
    self.output_disp.insert(0.0, binary_to_hex(bits))
```